# Angularjs & PHP JSON / ng-init / ng-repeat

Tags: php, angularjs, json

im trying to ng-repeat  from return php json result.But i have some error codes =)

angular.min.js:117 Error: [$parse:ueoe] **
Sorry for my english.

JSON result:

```
[{"id":"1","fullname":"Ad Soyad","email":"test@windowslive.com","tel":"12332123","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.","time":"12/05/2016","picture":"assets/admin/layout3/img/avatar1.jpg","isread":"1"},
{"id":"2","fullname":"Mahmut Tuncer","email":"test@windowslive.com","tel":"1233211","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.","time":"12/05/2016","picture":"assets/admin/layout3/img/avatar1.jpg","isread":"1"}]
```

a.php

```
$datacontactform = $sorgu = $dbquery->multisorgu('contactform');
   <ul  ng-init="contactlist = <?php echo $datacontactform; ?>">
    <li ng-repeat="data in contactlist"> {{data.fullname}}</li>
   </ul>
```

b.php

```
public function multisorgu($tablo,$where = null, $orderby = null, $limit = null){
    // MYSQL JSON RESULT    
    global $Baglan;
    $sorgu = mysqli_query($Baglan, "SELECT * FROM $tablo $where $orderby $limit");
    $result = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sorgu) > 0){
        while($bak = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sorgu)){
            $result[] = $bak;
        }
    }
    //UTF-8 JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
    $json_response = json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    return $json_response;
}
```

Comment: You could see JSON data in `ng-init` variable??

Comment: What happens if you try to print contactList like this: `<pre> {{contactList | json }}</pre>`

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why get error:**

```
<ul  ng-init="contactlist = <?php echo $datacontactform; ?>">
```

This line fires the error, as it likes `ng-init=" contactlist = somestring "`, but what ng-init except likes `ng-init=" contactlist = someobject"`.

**2. Solution:**

If use angular way, **Ajax** is a nice chooice.

If not, try this:

```
$datacontactform = $sorgu = $dbquery->multisorgu('contactform');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var datacontactform = JSON.parse('<?php echo $datacontactform; ?>');
</script>
   <ul  ng-init="contactlist = datacontactform ">
    <li ng-repeat="data in contactlist"> {{data.fullname}}</li>
   </ul>
```

Any problems let me know plz. Hope it works.

Comment: thank you for help . But ng-repeat not work. Because ng-init is not getting value

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're getting JSON String instead of Object in PHP variable. You could use **[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** method to parse a string into an object & If you're getting valid response from PHP, it should work. In Below example, I just hard coded `JSON` object within Controller for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>JSON PHP</title>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>

     var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
     app.controller('MyCtrlr', function ($scope, $http) {
                    //Store your JSON Response
                                 $scope.jsonResp = [{"id":"1","fullname":"Ad Soyad","email":"test@windowslive.com","tel":"12332123","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.","time":"12/05/2016","picture":"assets/admin/layout3/img/avatar1.jpg","isread":"1"},
{"id":"2","fullname":"Mahmut Tuncer","email":"test@windowslive.com","tel":"1233211","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.","time":"12/05/2016","picture":"assets/admin/layout3/img/avatar1.jpg","isread":"1"}];

                       //});

 });
</script>

<body>
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrlr">
         <ul  ng-init="contactlist = jsonResp">
            <li ng-repeat="data in contactlist"> {{data.fullname}}</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help guys. but i cant work

im trying to this way but now i cant work this json with ng-repeat..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
app.factory('jsonparse',function(){
    datacontactform = JSON.parse('<?php echo $datacontactform ?>'); 
    return datacontactform;
})
```

mycontroller :

```
 $scope.cd = datacontactform;
    console.log($scope.cd);
```

console result :

```
Object {1: Object, 2: Object}
1:Object
email:"tester@windowslive.com"
fullname:"tester tester"
id:"1"
isread:"1"
message:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat."
picture:"assets/admin/layout3/img/avatar1.jpg"
tel:"123123123"
time:"12/05/2016"
__proto__:
2:Object
email:"tester@windowslive.com"
fullname:"tester tester"
id:"1"
isread:"1"
message:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat."
picture:"assets/admin/layout3/img/avatar1.jpg"
tel:"123123123"
time:"12/05/2016"
__proto__:
```